# GRPC: Spring boot: How to warm up a grpc client. Especially to make it resolve domain names

Tags: spring-boot, grpc, grpc-java

The issue is: A grpc client is taking too much time on its first call. And after debugging, it was the domain name resolution that is taking that amount of time.

Is there any way to warm up the grpc clients just after the application starts?

**Update**: The request eventually succeeds, but the first call takes so much time, the consecutive calls are much faster.

And Im using this library https://github.com/yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter

Comment: Please update the grpc client code. How to connect to GRPC server?

Comment: @GowthamKK, I didn't understand your comment. What do you mean by "update the grpc client code"?

Comment: I mean that you need to update the code of grpc service connection in GRPC client (Mainly the url part)
Make sure you are following this naming conventions.
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/naming.md .
For example if you use http in url it might not get resolved because grpc does not resolve http urls.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misarticulated the issue. The request is succeeding, but the first request is taking around 1 second, and the consecutive requests are taking like 20 milliseconds

Answer (score 2):

When created, the ManagedChannel has not performed any I/O. It will lazily initialize itself on the first RPC or if you call [`managedChannel.getState(true)`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ManagedChannel.html#getState-boolean-).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how can I access it in a spring boot application?

Comment: Again thanks for the answer and +1 because this is how it should be done. But in the grpc library I am using, there is no way to access the managed channels :(

Comment: Issuing an RPC would be a workaround. You can do an RPC for any method, so you could use a stub for the HelloWorld example, which isn't implemented on your server, and it would still wake up the channel.

Comment: I tried this solution and am still seeing high latency on the first request

Comment: Java is very slow to start, especially the first time code is executed as it needs to classload. That's a different discussion than here. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53767396/4690866 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/47662646/4690866